# AsyncCallback not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, asyncsocket

Trying to implement Asynchronous Client/Server app in WinForms. Clientside code is as following:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AsyncClient
{
    public partial class AsyncClient : Form
    {
        public AsyncClient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //ManualResetEvent for notifying asyncronous threads that an event has occured
        private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        //Response from the remote device (server)
        private static String response = String.Empty;

        //start client
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
            try
            {
                var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtFromClient.Text); //convert message to bytes for sending over the wire
                using (clientSocket)/*(var clientSocket = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234)) *///make connection with the host
                {
                    clientSocket.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Loopback, 1234, new AsyncCallback(connectCallBack), clientSocket);
                    sendDone.WaitOne();
                    lblConnectionStatus.Text = "Connect is successfully established with the remote device.";
                    //send data to remote device
                    NetworkStream stream = clientSocket.GetStream(); //obtain network stream
                    stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length); //send data to the remote device
                    //sendDone.WaitOne();
                }
            }
           finally
            {
                clientSocket.Close();
            }
        }

        private static void connectCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                var clientSocket = (TcpClient)ar.AsyncState; //retrieve socket from state object (IAsyncResult)
                clientSocket.EndConnect(ar); //complete the connection
                connectDone.Set();
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }

        private void txtFromClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtFromClient.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

When I `button1` to send text, UI is freezing. During dubug mode I found that `AsyncCallback(connectCallBack)` in line

```
clientSocket.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Loopback, 1234, new AsyncCallback(connectCallBack), clientSocket);
```

is not firing and hence `connectCallBack` is not being executed. Program is rather halt on line

```
sendDone.WaitOne();
```

Any ideas why? Can someone please help?

Comment: Check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c359edfb-b6d9-4a21-bd82-ebbd2901d7e9/manualreseteventwaitone-hangs-my-application?forum=netfxbcl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are waiting for `sendDone.WaitOne();` and in your call back you use

```
connectDone.Set();
```

You should replace `sendDone.WaitOne();` with `connectDone.WaitOne();`

Comment: `connectDone.Set();` did solve the callback problem. UI is also not freezing anymore. First send from client is successfully received on the remote device. Problem is with sending the second send on client. Raising `System.InvalidOperationException` on line `NetworkStream stream = clientSocket.GetStream();` complaining 'The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets.'

Answer (score 2):

**Why the UI is freezing**: because you are trying to connect on the main thread so the UI becomes unresponsive. this is because the UI runs on the main thread. To solve this try to connect or receive on an different thread than the main threat.

**Why the callback is not called**: you should replace `sendDone.WaitOne();` with `connectDone.WaitOne();` because you are setting `connectDone.Set()` and you are waiting for `sendDone.WaitOne();`

Comment: `connectDone.Set();` did solve the callback problem. UI is also not freezing anymore. First send from client is successfully received on the remote device. Problem is with sending the second send on client. Raising `System.InvalidOperationException` on line `NetworkStream stream = clientSocket.GetStream();` complaining `The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets.`.

Comment: this is because your socket has been closed or the connection was broken probbebly in the    `finally { clientSocket.Close(); }`